# Retrive Image URL of Custom Fields in Theme

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I Have Created Custom Fields for Custom Post Type. when I retrieve the Values in Theme template image value returning 22. How can I get the image URL.?

```
<?php
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1, 
    'post_type'        => 'projects', 
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    );
    $projects = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ($projects as $project) { 
        echo $project->project_title; // Title Text
        echo $project->project_description; // Description Content
        echo $project->project_image; // 22

     } ?>
```

When i Print $project

```
WP_Post Object
(
    [ID] => 35
    [post_author] => 1
    [post_date] => 2017-04-07 05:50:29
    [post_date_gmt] => 2017-04-07 05:50:29
    [post_content] => Tekzenit
    [post_title] => Tekzenit
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] => publish
    [comment_status] => closed
    [ping_status] => closed
    [post_password] => 
    [post_name] => tekzenit
    [to_ping] => 
    [pinged] => 
    [post_modified] => 2017-04-07 06:12:54
    [post_modified_gmt] => 2017-04-07 06:12:54
    [post_content_filtered] => 
    [post_parent] => 0
    [guid] => http://10.180.82.8/fareed/?post_type=projects&p=35
    [menu_order] => 0
    [post_type] => projects
    [post_mime_type] => 
    [comment_count] => 0
    [filter] => raw
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just say:

```
get_the_post_thumbnail('', 'full')
```

just from the id itself since this is a custom meta.

```
wp_get_attachment_image($project->project_image, 'full')
```

Comment: i placed this tag `<?php echo "image".get_the_post_thumbnail($project->ID, 'full');?>` its not returing anything.

Comment: try the 2nd version now.  i updated.